# Mock a class method before making an object of that class in setUp

Tags: python, mocking, integration-testing

How can I use mock to avoid executing the `some_thing` method of `Settings` class and make it return some arbitrary string?

My class:

```
class Settings():
    """
    Represents settings. Will read the settings file if available.
    If not: will create it with defaults
    """
    def __init__(self):
    self.settings_file = os.path.join(pathlib.Path.home(), "settings.json")
    self.settings = self.get_defaults()
 
    def get_defaults(self):
        """ Get default settings """
        return {
            "other_path": self.some_thing()
        }

    def some_thing(self):
        return "value"
```

My test module:

```
"""
Unit tests for settings module
"""
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

from src.config.settings import Settings


class TestSettings(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Class containing tests for settings module """

    def setUp(self):
        """ Use this method to setup the tests """

        print() # this just prints a newline after module name printed by pytest
        self.settings = Settings()


    def test_get_settings_file(self):
        """
        Tests get setttings file
        """

        assert self.settings.settings_file == r"C:\users\root\.settings.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Settings`' class `init()` is executed in `setUp` before the `test_get_settings_file` is even ran. Solution is:

```
@mock.patch('src.config.settings.Settings.get_defaults', new=mock.Mock(return_value={}))
def setUp(self):
    cpode...
```

This just patches the parent method of the method I wanted to patch. For some reason patching out `some_thing` doesn't work though. I guess it's because mock cannot patch nested calls or something like that and that was exactly what I was struggling with

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **unittest.mock** library. Specifically, you will want to use the patch function from unittest.mock. Here's how you can modify your test module to achieve this:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
from src.config.settings import Settings

class TestSettings(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.settings = Settings()

    def test_get_settings_file(self):
        # Create a mock for the some_thing method
        with mock.patch.object(self.settings, 'some_thing', return_value='mocked_value'):
            assert self.settings.settings_file == r"C:\users\root\.settings.json"
```

The **mock.patch.object** context manager is used to replace the **some_thing** method of the **self.settings** instance with a mock function that returns the value '**mocked_value**'. This way, when the **get_defaults** method is called during the execution of **self.settings.settings_file**, the original **some_thing** method is not executed, and instead, the mock value is returned.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. But this doesn't do what I wanted. Thing is that the `Settings` class `init()` is executed in `setUp` before the `test_get_settings_file` is even ran.

Solution I found that worked was this

```
@mock.patch('src.config.settings.Settings.get_defaults', new=mock.Mock(return_value={}))
    def setUp(self):
```

Which seems fairly straightforward as it just patches the method I wanted. For some reason patching out `some_thing` doesn't work though. I guess it's because mock cannot patch nested calls or something like that and that was exactly what I was struggling with

Comment: @Zloj Write your answer please, and if you want accept it.